# Hide Ipad's keyboard, but still be able to enter into input field via custom keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have an input field where user enters numbers using "keyboard" made with css/html that is on the page. So, I do not need Ipad's keyboard to pop up. Almost all of the answers I found around suggests to defocus from the input field, by blur()-ing it. But I still need to enter into input field, find the caret position, replace,etc, so I still need to focus() in input field. Is there a way to make Ipad's keyboard to be hidden, and focus still be on input field?

Answer (score 0):

Please consult this link  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView and review the input view property of the UITextField which gives you the opportunity to replace the default keyboard with your own without dirty hacks simultaneously allowinf you to use the entire default textfield functionality!

However this might require you to stick with one or more protocols your custom kb has to implement!